# Configure two environment for kubernetes within Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, devops, kubernetes-ingress

Azure kubernetes service allows me to assign only one IP address to one cluster. I have created two namespaces within this cluster and I would like to distinguish those two namespaces by url as environments.

**Namespaces**

- stage
- dev

Desired access to those namespaces would be something like `{namespace}.cloudapp.azure.com`.

When defining ingress controller in each namespace the same ip address is assigned. How in general should I achieve this separation but keeping the same cluster?

Comment: Could clarify what exactly you want to achieve? Each LoadBalancer will get `ExternalIP` so if you will create 3 LB in your cluster, you will be able to reach your cluster using 3 external IP. When you are using ingress you can `redirect` traffic.

Comment: I want to achieve access my cluster via differenet domain url for each namespace. I might need to explore load balancers a little more. However, configuration on Azure allows me to assign only one IP per cluster but I could be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case you only need a single ingress controller. I.e. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/

To achieve this you need to add DNS entries for the namespaces leading to the single cluster IP.
If you only want to access the two DNS names:

- stage.cloudapp.azure.com
- dev.cloudapp.azure.com

adding both entries is probably sufficient if you only want a single application in those namespaces. If you want to deploy multiple applications within the namespaces you should consider adding wildcard DNS entries for:

- *.stage.cloudapp.azure.com
- *.dev.cloudapp.azure.com

With this setup you can add ingresses of the following format:

```
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: ingress-example-with-hostname
    namespace: dev
  spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service
            port:
              number: 80
```

For further informations take a look at this documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting

Comment: I found the solution in the meanwhile. Very much the same as linked to your answer. Additional to this I had to create new IP address with domain name on azure.